# How can I trace RESTEasy's dispatch?

Tags: resteasy

We're running RESTEasy 2.3.0.GA here and I'm struggling with a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219237/jax-rs-path-regex-fails-for-just-one-of-an-or-expression and I can't figure out how to get RESTEasy to fess'up why it thinks a particular URI is not mapped to my handler.  Is there some debug level I can crank up to get RESTEasy to reveal its dispatch?

Answer (score 3):

The docs are vague about what you'll get, but the Logger they are using log4j, logback, and java.util.logging. In my case, adding the following to logback.xml gives me some sparse information.

```
<logger name="org.jboss.resteasy.core" level="debug" />
<logger name="org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl" level="debug" />
<logger name="org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server" level="debug" />
```

http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.0.GA/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#RESTEasyLogging

Comment: None of those loggers output anything about what paths are registered.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class LoggingInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        if (REQUESTS_LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            final String method = containerRequestContext.getMethod();
            final String url = containerRequestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUri().toString();
            final StringBuilder headersStr = new StringBuilder();
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = containerRequestContext.getHeaders();
            for (MultivaluedMap.Entry<String, List<String>> header : headers.entrySet()) {
                headersStr.append(header.getKey()).append(": ").append(header.getValue()).append('\n');
            }
            String json = null;
            if ("POST".equals(method) || "PUT".equals(method)) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                IOUtils.copy(containerRequestContext.getEntityStream(), baos);
                byte[] jsonBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                json = new String(jsonBytes, "UTF-8");
                Object jsonObject = MAPPER.readValue(json, Object.class);
                json = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(jsonObject);
                containerRequestContext.setEntityStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonBytes));
            }
            REQUESTS_LOGGER.restCall(method, url, headersStr.toString(), json == null ? "empty" : json);
        }
    }
}
```